# How to display the current week now first in jquery fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

How to display the current week first in fullcalendar ?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMscJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do all of it unless you modify fullcalendar.js, but at least you can hide the previous and next month's weeks:

```
viewRender: function() {
    $(".fc-other-month").hide()
}
```

However, in your picture I noticed that your calendar cells in the past are highlighted. If you know the CSS class for that, you can use viewRender as above and just .hide() the cells with this CSS class.

Comment: thanks K48. However, Calendar need to update the new week in the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Just add ***defaultView: 'agendaWeek'***

Comment: Thanks you, I have to correct the core fullcanlendar.js and has successfully